# Font for tabs looks a little too big

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using the default for jQueryUI, but it looks like the font is a little big.
I know that one solution would be "WELL!  JUST MAKE IT SMALLER!", but I'm just wondering if I've messed something up or I don't have a value set correctly before I charge in and start changing things.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jqueryui", "1");
function OnLoadCallbackUI(){
    $('#tabs').tabs();
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoadCallbackUI);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        tabs-1
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        tabs-2
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demo page includes:

```
        body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
        .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
        #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
        #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
        ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
        ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't modify the jQuery CSS file.  Instead, use your own CSS to override it as needed.

Comment: I guess my question is: Why is it so big by default?  I mean: nobody uses it as that size, do they?  Maybe I should download a template from someone.